# OSX NSStatusBar statusbar icon dimensions?

Tags: cocoa

I couldn't find a document or hint which dimensions a statusbar or menubar icon in OSX should have. I found out that such an icon has 18x18 pixel for normal displays, but how to do that for retina displays? Is it 36x36 and are the usually naming coventions ...@2 working in this case?

The official apple docs covers informations of all other icon sizes, but nothing about a status bar icon.

Comment: Have you found the answer yet after more than two years? :D

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> When you create an icon to put inside a toolbar control in PDF format,
>   OS X will automatically scale your icon for high-resolution display.
>   You do not need to provide a high-resolution version.

there is no @2X version.

> For freestanding icons in a toolbar, create inviting images that are
>   easy to identify. Because freestanding toolbar icons do not need to
>   fit within a toolbar control, you have a little more room to express
>   them. As you design a freestanding icon for your toolbar, follow these
>   guidelines:
>
> Use a straight-on perspective. Make the outline sharp and clear. Use
>   anti-aliasing. Use color judiciously to add meaning. Create icons for
>   standard- and high-resolution displays. You need to supply two
>   resources: 32x32 and 32x32@2x. See Table 5-1 for the corresponding
>   canvas sizes. Use the PNG format.

[For reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000967-TPXREF102%28)

Comment: The document describes sizes for regular toolbars. Not for the statusbar.